# Resize iFrame Content Via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am wondering if theres some way to make it so that if there is a bunch of content in an iFrame it will just resize the document essentially so it fits. Making all the content inside the iFrame smaller. To clarify I want to resize the content, not the iFrame's size itself.

Any ideas how I would do this?

I have tried out some stuff but so far no luck.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
</script>
```

iFrame:

```
<iframe id="iframehtml" style="width:100%;height:100%;" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');"></iframe>
```

By the way the reason there is no src set for the iFrame is because I have it in JavaScript so when you click a a button it will edit the html of the iFrame via jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use load event to resize iframe

```
var iframe = document.getElementByID('your-iframe');
iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
  iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
})
```

Comment: Check my comment on aruuu's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using jQuery .contents() -

assuming *id* is the id of the element you wish to change within the iframe:

```
var frame = $('#iframehtml')
frame.contents().find(id).width = (newheight) + "px";
```

See http://forum.jquery.com/topic/changing-elements-in-an-iframe

Comment: The iFrame still has scroolbars when I click that.

Comment: What is the content within the iframe? Is _id_ the id of the iframe itself, or the id of the element you want to change within the iframe?

Comment: Well, there isn't actually a source of the iFrame, thats the issue. As I stated the content in the iFrame is actually just set using .contents().html('test') for example. Its not actually a source. Thats why I don't believe I can use a load function.

Comment: why are you using .contents.html('test') instead of $('#iframehtml').src = 'test'?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense at all.

Comment: Set the src attribute of the iframe to the url that you want it to display.